# Buffer a gz file from s3 using lambda nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

i have a gz file in s3 and need to fetch the content of the file. The below code doesn't print the actual content of the file.

```
const params = {
        Bucket: mybucket,
        Key: mykey.gz,

    };

    s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            const message = `Error getting object`;
            console.log(message);
            callback(message);
        } else {
            const payload = data.Body.toString('ascii');
            console.log('printing contents ', payload)
```

How can we fetch the contents of .gz file from s3?